# How to get html Id from Php Code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to get buttons Id in JavaScript from html, but problem is that html code is store in Php variable. How can I get buttons Id.

Thanks in advance.

My code:

==================================================================================

```
function img_up_image_uploader(){

    $html ='<div class="container">
            <div class="img_uploder">
                <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" id="**btnSubmit**" name="btnupload" value="Upload File" />
                    <input type="button" id="**btnPopup**" value="Upload File" />
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>';

    return $html;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var email = '<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>';
    if(email === ""){
        document.getElementById("btnPopup").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.display="none";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("btnPopup").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.display="block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReWrite it little bit:

```
$btnPop = "btnPopup";
$btnSub = "btnSubmit";

function img_up_image_uploader($btnPop, $btnSub){

$html ='<div class="container">
        <div class="img_uploder">
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" id="'.$btnSub.'" name="btnupload" value="Upload File" />
                <input type="button" id="'.$btnPop.'" value="Upload File" />
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>';

return $html;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var email = '<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>';
var btnPop = '<?php echo $btnPop; ?>';
var btnSub = '<?php echo $btnSub; ?>';
if(email === ""){
    document.getElementById("btnPopup").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.display="none";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("btnPopup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: Dear,  Both Id attribute are showing empty in browser.